# Road Trip food on the cheap

Tags: camping, cooking, stoves, europe, car-camping

I'm planning my first road trip with a friend. We're going from UK through France, probably Germany or maybe Belgium to Denmark and over to Sweden, back down to central France and then back home.

We'll be over the channel for 5 weeks all in all. I have a gas camp cooker. We'll be travelling from mid-June until mid-July. Not interested in meat really (it'll be hot and my travelling companion is veggie).

It would be great if you have any tips on good food items to buy and cook with on the road/ recipes that are cheap and easily doable or local goods that are tasty and cheap or any items that you can get in these countries that are great for road trips.

Looking forward to hearing your top tips :)

Comment: Are you planning to purchase in advance in England or purchase as you go along?

Comment: Hi. Anticipating to purchase as I go along.

Comment: What's the budget per day or per meal? Also which months are we talking about? This might make a difference in terms of the produce and fruits available locally.

Comment: It may be difficult getting Marmite in the Scandic countries, also Germany. Is that the sort of 'tip' you're after?

Comment: Don't operate your camp stove inside the car.

Comment: What kind of cooker is your camping cooker? The size and heat it generates will vary the answer

Comment: Since you will be able to buy new food as often as you want I am not sure this is an "outdoors" question... I think its better suited to the travel site, though they thought differently...

Answer (score 5):

This slightly depends on size and heat output or your stove, but camping stoves are universally good at one thing, heating water. So this makes them ideal for using with dyhydrated food's. These have come a long way from super and pot noodles and you can now get some pretty decent tasty food that you simply have to add water too, there are a couple of good suplpiers of these, like:

- http://www.expeditionfoods.com/
- http://www.mountainhouse.eu/

It also has the advantages of not taking up much space. They do do a lot of veggie options too.

they do have also few disadvantages:

- Expensive, £6 per person per meal can be a lot
- Limited number of flavours
- You need good supply of water to use them

---

Another option I can think of is eggs, Take plenty of **eggs** and you can generally make lot's of types of omelettes and spanish omlettes are particuarly tasty. Provided you get eggs from a supplier where the chickens are vacinated against salmonella (such as the [Lion mark in the UK](http://www.egginfo.co.uk/british-lion-eggs)) [you can keep them unrefrigerated](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2421530/So-eggs-fridge-Scientists-crack-age-old-argument-chilled-room-temperature-best.html)   for quite some time.

---

In the UK, find a chip shop. Every town or village will have one. A bag of chips will cost you about £1 and will easily feed one person (sometimes two). There is nothing more British than chips. Personally I like them swimming in malt vinegar, if the fist chip doesn't make you cough then you've not put enough vinegar on them!!

[image]

Comment: I think dehydrated foods are complete overkill for a road trip and way too expensive... As long as they aren´t in a big hurry you can cook most basic to easy meals (like suggested by nivag: pasta with sauce etc) on a camping stove, which I would always prefer because they are cheaper, fresh and tasty (well, depending on your cooking skills) and have more variety.

Comment: I hate pasta sauces though,bleu!

Answer (score 5):

Presuming you're planning on eating at/near your vehicle you're not really limited by the weight or bulk of the food. So, anything you can easily cook in 1 or 2 pots is a good bet. Generally, I have some version of pasta/rice/couscous and sauce. You can make your own sauce if you can get fresh ingredients or get reasonably cheap jars or dried packets.

I like adding some chorizo or similar spiced sausage to my sauces, particularly various red sauces. It keeps well and you can add it separately if people are vegetarian. Most places in Europe, definitely Germany and Italy, have there own varieties. They are also quite good for snacking, although some varieties may need cooking.

For breakfast, fried breakfasts are always good. Otherwise, if you can get fresh milk cereal is an option or bring powdered milk. I also like porridge, although it is a pain to clean. For porridge, I'd recommend a mix of half porridge oats and half ready brek/instant porridge, with powder milk that can be prepared in advance.